# Install full manjaro distribution with net installer?

Tags: linux, manjaro

I was hoping to save time and bandwidth by using the `manjaro` net installer.

I had hoped that it would be as easy as the other isos and I would be able to select which `dm` and `de` to use in the installer but save the time of the original ISO download but I can't find a way.

Is there possibly a `sudo pacman -Sy manjaro-desktop-xfce` similar to how Ubuntu has for it's distributions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groups for this purpose. For xfce just install group xfce4

To list all groups:

```
pacman -Sg
```

To install a group (like xfce4)

```
pacman -Sy xfce4
```

Then select the default value (all) to install all packages in the group.

Comment: So is there a way to install everything that would have come with the manjaro kde or xfce install isos? Or would I have to install all the grous one by one?

Comment: You have to install the groups for your required packages, there aren't too many groups.